# xbuild: Task GenerateResource FAILED, considers inexistent files newer than source file

Tags: linux, mono, xbuild

I've installed fresh mono and monodevelop to my debian from Xamarin source, and building two unrelated projects results in the same error:

```
% xbuild /verbosity:diagnostic
    Target GenerateResources:
    Task "GenerateResource"
            Using task GenerateResource from Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            Resource file 'obj/x86/Debug/WinFormsGraphicsDevice.MainForm.resources' is newer than the source file 'MainForm.resx', skipping.
            Resource file 'obj/x86/Debug/WinFormsGraphicsDevice.Properties.Resources.resources' is newer than the source file 'Properties/Resources.resx', skipping.
            Resource file 'obj/x86/Debug/OpenTK.GLControl.resources' is newer than the source file 'ThirdParty/GLControl/GLControl.resx', skipping.
    Task "GenerateResource" execution -- FAILED
```

Obviously files aren't there (in obj/x86/Debug there's only WinFormsGraphicsDevice.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt)

What's wrong here? I've spent three evening already getting ever new errors from Mono.

Comment: Multiple red flags. 1. WinForms on Mono is not bug free, so use GTK# if you can. 2. Latest Mono already supports MSBuild, which should be more reliable an option.

Comment: @LexLi I would actually like something cross-platform.

Comment: obviously you missed the fact that MSBuild is both open sourced and cross platform right now.

Comment: @LexLi I was talking about WinForms actually.

Comment: if I say Mono WinForms would give you more pains than joy (like I experienced previously on several projects), I am not sure if you would carefully listen. Anyway, you are on your own and you can try it out.

Comment: @LexLi mono seems to be the domain of pain anyway, can't imagine how I miss `mvn clean install`...

Comment: other parts are overall okay as they now use Microsoft source code whenever possible, but WinForms is such a monster itself, so a clone on Mono does not solve the incompatibility. Meanwhile, the apps look alien on Linux and macOS. If you use GTK# and Xamarin.Mac, it would be more pleasant.

Comment: @LexLi `MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.` sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by installing `mono-devel`, which apparently I did not have, that didn't prevent monodevelop from installing or compiling source, but that prevented xbuild from working properly and it could not tell me why.